# "Unknown user name or bad password" when accessing NAS through WCF service

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-security, impersonation, delegation

I have a web application client that is communicating with a WCF service.  Both the client and the service are running impersonation due to their need to write to a similar location on the NAS for purposes of writing logs and working files.  The issue is that while the client can write fine, the service can not.  Both are using `System.IO.FileStream` to write to the NAS.  We initially thought it may be due to an improperly passed credential so enabled delegation for the domain user.  We have still received the same error.  If I check the `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity` I can see that it is the domain user that I would expect but the strange thing is that the `IIdentity.AuthenticationType` value is "Kerberos".  Using [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383) article we have checked our IIS `NTAuthenticationProviders` and verified that it is set to "Negotiate,NTLM".  I realize this IIS setting is for the communication between IIS and not the NAS but we wanted to be sure.
We have also performed a trace and can see the negotiation between the server in question and the NAS location.  After the request is sent we do see it try to contact a Domain Controller but since this is not configured it fails authentication.
In the end, I'm simply trying to find out if there is a configuration directive that I can set to prevent it from trying to use Kerberos authentication when writing to the NAS and, secondly, why the service is using Kerberos when the client is not. 
I will gladly edit this and add any further configuration items requested so please let me know.

WCF Service web.config binding section

```
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="default" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the items in this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx

Items in step 8 might help or point you in the right direction.